# app crashes when launching emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

My logcat:

```
01-01 05:13:28.690: D/AndroidRuntime(696): Shutting down VM
01-01 05:13:28.690: W/dalvikvm(696): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfunapp/com.example.myfunapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:259)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.example.myfunapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-01 05:13:28.741: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  ... 11 more
01-01 05:13:33.503: I/Process(696): Sending signal. PID: 696 SIG: 9
```

Its says "Unfortunately myapp has closed", I did include @android:id/list at the ListView in the xml file. But it still gives me the same error upon launching of the emulator. Please help, quite new to this..

This is my MainActivity.java class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fun_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.takePhoto:
            cam();
            return true;
        case R.id.music:
           startActivity(new Intent(this, MPlayer.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}


  public void cam() {
Intent intent = new     Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "my-photo.jpg"); 
            Uri photoPath = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoPath);


           startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
```

This is MPlayer.java class for implementing a music player. I have used switch case in my MainActivity. One is for the music player and the other for the camera API in android.
I have called a method directly which I implemented in my MainActivity for the Camera option. However for the music player, I created a new class called MPlayer.java containing the code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.myfunapp.Mp3Filter;
import com.example.myfunapp.R;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;


class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter{
public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
    return(name.endsWith(".mp3"));
}

 public static class MPlayer extends ListActivity{

private static final String SD_PATH =new String("/sdcard/");
private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.msicplayer);
    updatePlayList();


    Button stopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopBtn);
    stopPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.stop();

        }
    });
```

}

```
private void updatePlayList(){
    File home = new File(SD_PATH);
    if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0){
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())){
            songs.add(file.getName());
        }
ArrayAdapter<String> songList =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.song_item,songs);
        setListAdapter(songList);
    }
}
```

}
}

This is my music player layout code:

```
<LinearLayout 

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >




<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>




<Button
    android:id="@+id/stopBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stopBtn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Paste the xml and java code plz

Comment: add it with `android:id="@+id/list"` not `@android:id/list`

Comment: Are you extending activty or listactivity

Comment: here i posted all the xml code. I am extending listactivity

Answer (score 0):

As the error log indicates, Android is unable to find a view with the right id. This is probably because you need to add it as,

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the import package of R class. 
There is 2 R classes, one is of android system, and another is your one.
Make sure you import your R class by [your_package_name].R